# Upgrade ASP.net MVC2 to MVC4 Razor views intellisense not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have upgraded my ASP.net MVC 2 application to latest MVC 4 with VS 2013 community edition.

Everything is completely perfect everything works expect one annoying thing i tried a lot but i didn't find any solution.

In my razor views it shows me that the Styles, Script, Html.RenderPartial as the following:

The name 'Scripts' does not exist in the current context

During the run time i had no issue at all only during the modification of the view in visual studio:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPAWJ.png

I tried to add the namespaces in the web.config file (root and the one inside the views) but it doesn't help also, i have the following config:

Root web.config:

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
    <add namespace="System.Linq" />
    <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
    <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

View web.config:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

I tried to restart visual studio a lot, de-attach and attach the project again with no success :(

Any suggestion or help is really appreacted becuase i would to convert my whole project from aspx/ascx to cshtml

Comment: install the  `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` nuget package

Comment: There are many posts about this but one of the best option is to create a new project in ASP.NET MVC 4 and move all the files to the new solution. Unfortunately, every ASP.NET version changes config files, references, etc. and that makes it hard to upgrade.

Comment: @too_cool that package was already installed:
'Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization 1.1.3' already installed.

Comment: @FranciscoGoldenstein yes i see a lot of different posts about issues of the upgrade, but i'm trying to avoid creating another project :( maybe it's something small i need to change or add

Comment: Check both web configs, the one in the root of the project and the one in Views folder. Verify the version of each reference and compare it to MS's documentation.

Comment: @MohamedNoor  Have you tried like this `@section Scripts{
    <script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/jqueryval")"></script>
}`

Comment: Try this.http://sebnilsson.com/a53db714/making-mvc-3-razor-intellisense-work-after-installing-mvc-4-beta/

Comment: @AdershM I tried, but unfortunitly still the same issue, I have the following as appSettings:
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

Comment: @too_cool your code works! also with out System.Web.Optimization works but it shows a red line below it and no errors during the run time

Comment: @FranciscoGoldenstein I have this:<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" /> in both files

Comment: @MohamedNoor  Grt!! it works.... the red line shows bcz it doesn't understand..Try `Clean` the solution and `Rebuild again`..

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

```
@section Scripts{
    <script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/jqueryval")"></script>
}
```

Comment: I still have to add the name space, this doesn't show any error:
@System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/Assets/css/style")
But this shows errors:
@Styles.Render("~/Assets/css/style")

Both works well.

Comment: @MohamedNoor  Is there any thing more i can help..?

Comment: thanks for your help, but i think i will go with a new project ;-(